# How to access paragraph inside table td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue accessing a paragraph inside a table td using jquery.

What I want to do is to **hide the paragraph** inside **table td** if the value is X for example.

This is my code. The value is being select but the hiding is not working.

```
var Privileges = jQuery('.woocommerce-checkout #customer_details 
   .woocommerce-billing-fields #billing_country');
    var select = this.value;
   Privileges.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'RO') {

     $( "#wc-local-pickup-plus-toggle-default-handling" ).show();
    }

   else $('#wc-local-pickup-plus-toggle-default-handling').hide();
});
```

Here is the inspected element image. I have no idea why its not working.
[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Try putting `console.log($(this).val());` directly inside your change handler, and see if you are in fact getting the correct value when it changes in your debug console.

Comment: you can select it like jQuery('td > p').  this means select all p elements that are children of td elements, so it will return an array if you have more than one p as a child of a td. If it is the only p that is a child of a td then you can do jQuery('td > p').hide() if you need help narrowing that selector down let me know

Comment: As i can see you `.woocommerce-checkout` is a **Form**  `#customer_details` is a  **Div** and this can't got event **Change**

Comment: @RobertWade yes the value is correct in console

Comment: @headmax and what should i do ? any idea ty

Comment: @AgnesPandek did you tryed my example?

Comment: @AgnesPandek from your url site : `class="select2-search__field"` just added the part of your html.

Comment: @headmax your code is not working,the value is being selected with the code i have , the problem is the access to the paragraph inside that table :/

Comment: Sorry didn't tested is an i think is a "plugin" specific to woocommerce and yes this no running cos you got some other observer that catch the event before my code try to take the info i guess. i try your way .

Answer (score 0):

Its looking like the problem in your code is here:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'RO')
```

try changing this to

```
if ($(this).find(':selected').val() == 'RO')
```

To summarize, the listener is added to the select box, so in the listener, 'this' refers to the select element. Which doesn't have a value.

$(this).find(':selected') finds any sub element that has the "selected" property, which in this cas we know will be an option, which should have a value.

Comment: maybe you can make a quick account https://barbutonatural.com so you can see the checkout after you add a product?This paragraph is from a plugin so maybe it loads later one ? I am not an expert :).Thank you.

Comment: Which page is this on?

Comment: in checkout , add a product to cart check poland or romania country since those are in the zone at the moment

Comment: alright, I updated my answer to reflect your situation

Comment: the value is not the issue , it selects the value , the problem is it cannot get to the paragraph inside that from table.

Comment: Actually it looks like something is readding it. Through debugger I can confirm that selecting RO did not enter your IF statement. It does now, however, it looks like something after the change shows the paragraph again (if you add a break at the else statement, you can see the element hide, and then when you exit the debugger it reappears)

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `<select>` elements don't have a value? The value is the value of the selected element.

Comment: @Barmar Hey man, im just saying the val on $(this) was undefined while the val on $(this).find(':selected') came up with data.
Ill try and poke around your files to see why the element is hiding and then reappearing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table td").children().find('p').hide();
```

If you added the element dynamically use the following:

```
Privileges.on('change', function(){  
   // your code here 
});
```